# Help! My calculator malfunctions!

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, integer

### Introduction

My calculator is behaving weird. Sometimes when I type in an `8` it displays a `2`. And sometimes when I type in a `6` it displays a `+`. Some buttons are mixed up!
Could anyone help me determine which?

### Challenge:

**Input:** List of *incorrect* equations, with *correct* results.

**Output:** The two buttons that are swapped.

**For example:**
An input could be:

```
123    = 3
8423   = 252
4+4    = 8
4*7-10 = 417
9/3    = 3
42-9   = -36
```

For which the expected outputs are: `2` and `*`.

Why? Because ALL the equations would be correct if we swap the 2's and *'s:

```
1*3    = 3
84*3   = 252
4+4    = 8
427-10 = 417
9/3    = 3
4*-9   = -36
```

### Challenge rules:

- Input can be in any reasonable format. Can be a single string with space delimited; a string-list or -array; a list with equations and another list with the correct results. Your call. Please state which input format you've used!
  NOTE: This also means you are allowed to input the test case `-5--15` as `-5- -15` or `-5 - -15`. However, a number resulting in `--` should either be inputted without spaces or with a space between every digit. So test case `9119` can be inputted like `9119` or `9 1 1 9` (reason `91 19` isn't allowed is because you can then be guided by the space for finding `- -`). So spaces are (somewhat) optional and allowed.
- Output format can be in any reasonable format as well. Can be two characters; a single two-character string; a string-list containing the two characters. Your call. Again, please state which output format you've used!
- You are allowed to use any distinct 14 outputs that map to `0123456789+-*/`. So you are even allowed to output two distinct integers if you want to (again, please specify the mapping you've used, if any).
- You only have to support integers. So there won't be any test cases like `1/8=0.125` or `1/8=0`.
- Arithmetic operands you'll have to support: addition (`+`); subtraction (`-`); multiplication (`*` or `×` or `·`); division (`/` or `÷`). (NOTE: Characters between parenthesis are only added as clarification.)
- You'll have to support negative numbers. This means `-` can be interpreted in the equation as both a mathematical operand or a negative indicator.
- You can assume the given incorrect equations and supposed correct equations are always valid (so there won't be things like `4-/2` or `9+-+8` for example).
- The incorrect input-equations can contain a division by 0, but the corrected and expected equations will never contain division by 0.
- The incorrect input-equations can already be correct even if you swap the intended buttons back.
- A given input equation can be irrelevant for the buttons  to swap (like the `4+4=8` and `9/3=3` equations, with the swapped buttons `2` and `*`).
- You can assume there will always be only one possible swap that can be made with the given test cases.
- Both buttons to swap will always be present in at least one of the incorrect equations.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Test cases:

```
Input:
123    = 3
8423   = 252
4+4    = 8
4*7-10 = 417
9/3    = 3
42-9   = -36

Output: 2 *

Input:
4/2   = 6
3/0   = 3
0/8+2 = 4
95-5  = 90
4+2   = 2

Output: + /

Input:
7+4    = 11
5-15   = 46
212-23 = -2121

Output: 1 -

Input:
4+8/2-9*1 = -5
99/3-13   = 20
1+2+3+4   = 10
4-3-2-1   = -6

Output: 2 4

Input:
18/18  = 1
98-8   = 90
55*88  = 4840
-5--15 = 10

Ouput: 5 8

Input:
9119    = 18
5-3     = 513
8*-9    = 152
13116/3 = -1

Output: 1 -
```

Comment: "real division" means we have to support floats?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oops.. Copied that from a previous arithmetic challenge of mine. Removed, and as answer to your question, no you only have to deal with integers.

Comment: Oh, so we'll never have to deal with something like `4/3=1` right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That's right. I'll specify that more clearly in the challenge.

Comment: I'd suggest a test case where a correct equation contains `--`. For example `1991 = 2, -/3 = 3`. (Many languages confuse this with the decrement operator.)

Comment: @nwellnhof Added a test case with `9119=18` -> `9--9=18`. And also specified that you are allowed to input the test cases with spaces, since I've seen multiple people add code to change `-5--15` to `-5- -15` programmatically, while just inputting it with a space is perfectly allowed.

Comment: Is it also allowed to input `9119` as `91 19`?

Comment: @nwellnhof Hmm.. Why not. If you want you can even add spaces between every number. I was doubting for a moment, since technically `9119` is one number, and you don't know beforehand if it should be replaced with `--`. If I had a test case like `9119=9229` and `2+2=2` [`1 2`], it would be weird to input it like `91 19`. On the other hand, you don't need to output `92 29`, but only `1 2` (the pair to swap), so yes, you are allowed to input it like `91 19`.

Comment: The problem is that adding a space in `91 19` if the solution is `9--9` and no space in `9119` if the solution is `9229` requires knowledge about the solution when creating the test cases. If this were allowed, I could simply add a space only before the swapped characters and the solution could be immediately derived from the test case.

Comment: @nwellnhof Hmm, good point, hadn't thought of that. I actually meant you should either always add a space in numbers like `9119`, or never. Not sometimes based on the test case. Will have to think about it for a moment, but maybe `9119` as single number is a more natural input-format (although spaces between every character would still be allowed).

Comment: Maybe we can say that your calculator just has a display problem but it still formatting the input correctly with a space before the unary `-`, no matter what character is shown instead? ;-)

Comment: Is evaluation left-to-right, or `*` and `/` before `+` and binary `-`?

Comment: @aschepler It's `*` and `/` before `+` and `-`. So you'd input the entire equation, and then click `=` to get the result.

Comment: @Arnauld I can understand why you'd say that. ;) But there are a few minor problems: you always know it's `- -` when a space is present between two equal characters/digits. And if I would add spaces between every mathematical operand (`+-*/`), you can be guided by the spaces regarding solving the swaps, as _nwellnhof_ mentioned above. So I thought about it carefully, but `9119` should be either `9119` or `9 1 1 9`. (You can easily alter your answer anyway by adding a `.replace('--','- -')`.) Sorry that I said it was allowed in my comment before.. I wish these things were said in the Sandbox :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>132</s> 113 bytes

*Thanks to Jo King for -19 bytes.*

```perl6
->\e,$r {first {($!=e.trans($_=>.flip))ne e&&try "all {$!.&{S:g/\-/- /}} Z==$r".EVAL},[X~] (|^10,|<+ - * />)xx 2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9NT8JAEIbv/IqBNPRzusy0C7tqSTxw82ZijKKGQzEklZDCAVLqX6@zkJiyh9mPd993ntmVdTXtfk7graHocL4sE6@GZr2p9wdoAm9YlOmhXm33gfdVzNN1tdmF4baEcjw@1CcYraoKGm@Yjpvnu2@1RIWg2hbeisKrR@ni5fGpTd5ffz8gOH/SJDk/xIAQgZqHxyNw2@1XrnXgk7XkJwO4Lp/98H7wr3GWgMldzeNcSjRDyQKr3Auj7RnlhTXLd1FoloDcMZv203IlcqbEP1EmlrPVqF0y92KmF6f0svLvBmbmCDSSWJgYOeu5iMQjVhSFbnrGRglnJLoVaiQJp5jj7DIOZsjYn97xsDR2Q@INPBlFMpo1KFXryMiGGgWnj3HFzk1@yRB/9wc)

Input is a comma-separated string of equations and a comma-separated string of results (hope this is OK). Output is a string containing the two swapped buttons.

Correctly handles `--`. Might product false positives for `---`, `++`, `**`, or `//`, but I couldn't come up with a test case.

Comment: You don't have to handle `---`;`++`;`**`;`//`; or other things like `*+` etc. The only double adjacent non-digit you'll have to support is `--`. Also, if I understand your code correctly, you won't need `.subst('-','- '`, since inputting the test case `-5--15` with a space is allowed. You aren't the first to add code to add this space programmatically, so I'll specify this more clearly in the challenge description.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I might have to handle things like `**` because they have a meaning as Perl 6 expressions and might cause false positives. `1992 = 1` could be `1**2 = 1` or `1//2 = 1`, for example. The `subst` is for cases where the correct equation contains `--`, for example the new test case you added.

Comment: Your answer is currently the one with the least amount of bytes, so I'll accept it for now. If someone comes up with something shorter, the check might shift again.

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY9NT8JAEIbv/IqBNPRzusy0C7tqSTxw82ZijKKGQzEklZDCAVLqX6@zkJiyh9mPd993ntmVdTXtBj8n8NZQdDhflolXQ7Pe1PsDNIE3LMr0UK@2@8D7KubputrswnBbQjkeH@oTjFZVBY03TMfN8923WqJCUG0Lb0Xh1aN08fL41Cbvr78fEJw/aZKcH2JAiEDNw@MRuO32K9c68Mla8pMBXJfPfng/@Nc4S8DkruZxLiWaoWSBVe6F0faM8sKa5bsoNEtA7phN@2m5EjlT4p8oE8vZatQumXsx04tTeln5dwMzcwQaSSxMjJz1XETiESuKQjc9Y6OEMxLdCjWShFPMcXYZBzNk7E/veFgauyHxBp6MIhnNGpSqdWRkQ42C08e4Yucmv2Q4f/cH "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>159</s> 158 bytes

*Edit: new version to comply with the updated rules regarding `--`*
*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

Takes input in currying syntax `(e)(r)` where ***e*** is the array of equations and ***r*** is the array of expected results. Returns an array of characters.

```js
e=>r=>(l=[...2**29+'4+-*/']).filter(x=>l.some(y=>eval("try{eval((S=(s=`[${e}]`).replace(/./g,c=>c==x?y:c==y?x:c)).split`--`.join`+`)+''==r&S!=s}catch(e){}")))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

e=>r=>(l=[...2**29+'4+-*/']).filter(x=>l.some(y=>eval("try{eval((S=(s=`[${e}]`).replace(/./g,c=>c==x?y:c==y?x:c)).split`--`.join`+`)+''==r&S!=s}catch(e){}")))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f
  ([ '123', '8423', '4+4', '4*7-10', '9/3', '42-9' ])
  ([ 3, 252, 8, 417, 3, -36 ])
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f
  ([ '4/2', '3/0', '0/8+2', '95-5', '4+2' ])
  ([ 6, 3, 4, 90, 2 ])
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f
  ([ '7+4', '5-15', '212-23' ])
  ([ 11, 46, -2121 ])
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f
  ([ '4+8/2-9*1', '99/3-13', '1+2+3+4', '4-3-2-1' ])
  ([ -5, 20, 10, -6 ])
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f
  ([ '18/18', '98-8', '55*88', '-5--15' ])
  ([ 1, 90, 4840, 10 ])
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(f
  ([ '9119', '5-3', '8*-9', '13116/3' ])
  ([ 18, 513, 152, -1 ])
));
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
e => r =>                                  // given e and r
  (l = [...2 ** 29 + '4+-*/'])             // generate l = [...'5368709124+-*/']
  .filter(x =>                             // for each character x of l
    l.some(y =>                            // for each character y of l
      eval("try {                          // we need to 'try', because we don't know
        eval(                              // whether the following expression is valid
          (S = (s = `[${e}]`).             // s = list of equations coerced to a string
            replace(/./g, c =>             // S =
              c == x ? y : c == y ? x : c  //   s with x and y exchanged
            )                              // end of replace()
          ).split`--`.join`+`              // replace '--' with '+'
        ) + '' == r                        // does the resulting list match r?
        & S != s                           // and was at least one character modified?
      } catch(e){}")                       // if we try, we oughta catch
    )                                      // end of some()
  )                                        // end of filter()
```

Comment: I think you can save a byte by `eval`ing the `try / catch`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzRrLp.

Comment: @Shaggy Ah yes, nice one. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJParY) might work for 139 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran a full test suite and spotted that.

Comment: Doesn't work for `1991 = 2`. The solution should be `1--1 = 2` with `9` and `-` swapped.

Answer (score 4):

## Oracle SQL & PL/SQL, 458 Bytes

> Input can be in any reasonable format. [...] a list with equations and another list with the correct results.

Compile the PL/SQL function (210 bytes):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(x CHAR,y CHAR)RETURN NUMBER IS o NUMBER;BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1:='||REPLACE(x,'--','- -')||';END;'USING OUT o;RETURN CASE o WHEN y THEN 1 END;EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN 0;END;
```

Run the SQL (248 bytes):

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM T,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM T)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

After having create a table `T` with the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE T(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '123',    3     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '8423',   252   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4+4',    8     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4*7-10', 417   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '9/3',    3     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '42-9',   -36   FROM DUAL
```

Output:

```
V V_1
- ---
2 *
* 2
```

**Previous Version**:

Assumed a string input like `'123  = 3'`:

Same PL/SQL function and the SQL (322 bytes):

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15),y(x,y)AS(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t,'[^=]+'),REGEXP_SUBSTR(t,'-?\d+$')FROM T)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM y,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM T)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

After having create a table `T` with the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE T(T) AS
  SELECT '123    = 3'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '8423   = 252' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4+4    = 8'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4*7-10 = 417' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '9/3    = 3'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '42-9   = -36' FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
V V_1
- ---
2 *
* 2
```

**Update - Testing**:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F(x CHAR,y CHAR)RETURN NUMBER IS o NUMBER;BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1:='||REPLACE(x,'--','- -')||';END;'USING OUT o;RETURN CASE o WHEN y THEN 1 END;EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN 0;END;
/

CREATE TABLE A(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '123',    3     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '8423',   252   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4+4',    8     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4*7-10', 417   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '9/3',    3     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '42-9',   -36   FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE B(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '4/2',    6     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/0',    3     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0/8+2',  4     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '95-5',   90    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4+2',    2     FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE C(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '7+4',    11    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '5-15',   46    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '212-23', -2121 FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE D(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '4+8/2-9*1', -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '99/3-13',   20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+2+3+4',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4-3-2-1',   -6 FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE E(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '18/18',  1     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '98-8',   90    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '55*88',  4840  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-5--15', 10    FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE G(X,Y) AS
  SELECT '9119',    18   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '5-3',     513  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '8*-9',    152  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '13116/3', -1   FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM A,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM A)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1/0)**:

```
| V | V |
|---|---|
| 2 | * |
| * | 2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM B,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM B)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1/1)**:

```
| V | V |
|---|---|
| + | / |
| / | + |
```

**Query 3**:

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM C,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM C)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1/2)**:

```
| V | V |
|---|---|
| 1 | - |
| - | 1 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM D,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM D)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1/3)**:

```
| V | V |
|---|---|
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
```

**Query 5**:

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM E,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM E)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1/4)**:

```
| V | V |
|---|---|
| 5 | 8 |
| 8 | 5 |
```

**Query 6**:

```
WITH r(v)AS(SELECT SUBSTR('1234567890-+*/',LEVEL,1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<15)SELECT r.v,s.v FROM G,r,r s WHERE r.v<>s.v GROUP BY r.v,s.v HAVING SUM(f(TRANSLATE(x,r.v||s.v,s.v||r.v),y))=(SELECT COUNT(1)FROM G)AND SUM(INSTR(x,r.v)+INSTR(x,s.v))>0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6746/1/5)**:

```
| V | V |
|---|---|
| 1 | - |
| - | 1 |
```

Comment: No need for `||REPLACE(x,'--','- -')||`, input/output format is flexible, so you are allowed to input `-5--15` as `-5- -15` if you want to. Also, what would be the easiest way for me to verify all the test cases work, especially the last one? Is a TIO-link somehow possible?

Comment: Or is the `||REPLACE(x,'--','- -')||` used for an expected correct equation, like the last test case I've added?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `--` starts a comment in SQL, so either the test cases need to be formulated so that `--` never occurs in the equation (replacing it with `- -`) or it needs some defensive coding to militate for that.

Comment: So for the last test case `13116/3 = -1` would need to be written as `131 16/3 = -1` to remove that call to `REPLACE`.

Comment: Ah ok, so the replace is indeed used for the expected correct equations. Thanks for adding the SQL fiddle, +1 from me.

Comment: +1 for using a language that's terribly useless for this kind of challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>204</s>, <s>199</s>, <s>193</s>, <s>173</s>, 165 bytes

- From 199 bytes to 193 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcode
- From 193 bytes to
  173 bytes thanks to Halvard Hummel

```python
s=input()
r=str.replace
t=set(''.join(zip(*s)[0]))
for i in t:
 for j in t:
	try:
	 if all(eval(r(r(r(e,i,'$'),j,i),'$',j))==v*(i<j)for e,v in s):print i,j
	except:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxRi8IwEISfza/Iw0F2y9ZrxUIs5peID0UibihpSPbKeX@@GjkGhvmYYdJTHks8bFtxHNOPAKrsiuR99mmebl6JK17AmH1YOMIfJ2gKXrororovWbPmqGVUukL4h53k59s13/U0z@DXaYb8kScm82WQAjHWRAHRubUBPgesH57W@lJwTJmjaKagdv735pOM3bZdwPT2u7eGdI8E5mRbazSdugrD0Nh3c7THD7ZD2/ZDXXZ4fQE)

Comment: [I think it fails for the last test case](https://tio.run/##RYzBDsIgGIPP8hQcTPhR0KFD2RKexHiYipEFkWy4zKefYKJemn5t0/CKt4ffTFOvrQ/PCBQ5fTiiqEkhNttS7vaqWi/4kqDro8MWW49jjXCG9gt41EXSnBk25LSv0Sx2r3pc6ubUgxkaB2bVmeCaswHLyJzQH7bM/iE1rKWUDxTNzHg2IeYTke7dqgnB@AvAyGzeoNBZH/HdenB0mg5AhFoLRZigDEileLJVkb2UC5WgVOUHueRcyLQr6PEN).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanx for the remark, I'm fixing it..

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder here is the corrected version

Comment: [193 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY7RasQgEEWf41f4UNDZHbdJ2YAb8EtCHtLFUsUaURuyu/TbUw3zMufMvTDhkb8X/7HvSRkffjMHElXK8RJ1cPNdk6ySzpyxi12M508T@CnB2E4AxKlxIl9LpIYaT/NAaAV7gHiZv4E0m2pJU63GtfpUHM3xMWxnNX8mrtfZ8XiMRoPsjQFaNFA3tABihVLQ212HXDsdadxZ8a1kLSAJ0fhMf8pjDvZ95KyT751kSDtAzm5SSEbx1lbo@5Msl6u8Hih6Ibq@JluY/gE)

Comment: [173 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYzRisMgFESf61f4sKC3XLtxacBa8iWlD1IseyUYURs2XfbbszEMDHOYYdJSv6f4ta5loJheVQLLQ6n5lH0a3cOzOhRfpRCnMFGUb0ryWODW3QHYc8qcOEVeLeMNwg7ql/4sO9S8bM7pyV1cpJ/dKPMuj4TiQwAGJGgJA4Ca9wePc/soYB07@J@HT9XqLY3F25QpVk4Yrm5db1Jo86mNQK4BpbgYZQTHS9eg749ma87mvKPqldJ9W3Zw/wc)

Comment: @HalvardHummel very nice

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>222</s> <s>209</s> 192 bytes

```
param($x)1..13|%{0..(($i=$_)-1)|%{$a,$b='+-*/0123456789'[$i,$_]
$a+$b|?{!($x|%{$e,$r=$_-split'='
try{$r-(-join$(switch($e|% t*y){$a{$b}$b{$a}default{$_}})-replace'-',' -'|iex)}catch{1}}|gu)}}}
```

Test script and explanation:

```
$f={

param($x)                               # array of strings with equations
1..13|%{                                #
    0..(($i=$_)-1)|%{                   # $i and $_ contains unique couples of different indecies
        $a,$b='+-*/0123456789'[$i,$_]  # $a and $b contains buttons to swap
        $g=$x|%{                        # for each equation from array
            $e,$r=$_-split'='           # split incorrect expression and correct result
            $e=-join$(switch($e|% t*y){ # swap buttons for each symbol in the expression
                $a{$b}
                $b{$a}
                default{$_}
            })
            $e=$e-replace'-',' -'       # insert a space before each '-'.
                                        # It need to work with negative numbers.
                                        # For example, '4--1' throws an exception, '4 - -1' returns '5'
            try{$r-($e|iex)}catch{1}    # Try to calc $e as powershell expression
                                        # return 0 if the expression result equal to the result of the calculation
                                        # return non zero integer otherwise
        }|gu                            # Get-unique of calculation for each equation
        if(!$g){                        # if $g is 0 or $null
                                        # then all calculations returns true
            $a+$b                       # Ok, return the couple of buttons
        }
    }
}

}

@(
    ,('2*','123=3','8423=252','4+4=8','4*7-10=417','9/3=3','42-9=-36')
    ,('/+','4/2=6','3/0=3','0/8+2=4','95-5=90','4+2=2')
    ,('1-','7+4=11','5-15=46','212-23=-2121')
    ,('42','4+8/2-9*1=-5','99/3-13=20','1+2+3+4=10','4-3-2-1=-6')
    ,('1-','9119=18','5-3=513','8*-9=152','13116/3=-1')
) | % {
    $e,$x=$_
    $r=&$f $x
    "$($e-eq$r): $r : $x"
}
```

Output:

```
True: 2* : 123=3 8423=252 4+4=8 4*7-10=417 9/3=3 42-9=-36
True: /+ : 4/2=6 3/0=3 0/8+2=4 95-5=90 4+2=2
True: 1- : 7+4=11 5-15=46 212-23=-2121
True: 42 : 4+8/2-9*1=-5 99/3-13=20 1+2+3+4=10 4-3-2-1=-6
True: 1- : 9119=18 5-3=513 8*-9=152 13116/3=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
SÙãʒË_}ʒ¹sÂ‡„--'+:.EQ
```

Input as two lists, first being the equations and second being the results. Output as a filtered list of pairs with both rotations (i.e. `[["2","*"],["*","2"]]`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@PDMw4tPTTrcHV97atKhncWHmx41LHzUME9XV13bSs/18PrA//@jlQwt9A0tlHSULC10QZSpqZYFiNY11dU1NFWK5Yo21LE00DGxMDHQMTSIBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JVAxTkMxDN05RZUF6ccmsZP8n7B0AaSOCIGoqgoVwcrCXKliYGFBf2NBQhyAQ2TrMXqRj50usf30nt9zfNo80vPUXy3q5@3czDYvTzMzX1zcSX94H6WfbupX/d2P9eNhux/vX@vbYfdz2H0jntrzs8v6t7yetjCtDHEwYHJsJdqobzcgeWmKayBjMeuTVQBODBkiDRAAQy@YiY6FEpzSvctWp5IwtWWssl7IEYoHVv7QHBKSMpgYxVdwIog9oADUttrsxLUj3SYpkDQIWbbhmBADMpIqMQF7IA/Y8lB2lFWVUUtKXdaKCdVSnTRKzFE1KihEpSVq39ChDhSIencMliFRAJLLkdb/). (NOTE: Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E in the TIO, because `.E` is disabled in the newer version on TIO. Because of that, an additional `ï` (cast to integer) is added, because in the legacy version of 05AB1E `1.0` and `1` inside lists were not equal.)

**Explanation:**

```python
S              # Convert the (implicit) input-list of equations to a list of characters
               # (which implicitly flattens)
               #  i.e. ["18/18","98-8","55*88","-5--15"]
               #   → ["1","8","/","1","8","9","8","-","8","5","5","*","8","8","-","5","-","-","1","5"]
 Ù             # Only leave all unique characters
               #  → ["1","8","/","9","-","5","*"]
  ã            # Cartesian product with itself; creating each possible pair of characters
               #  → [["1","1"],["1","8"],["1","/"],["1","9"],["1","-"],["1","5"],["1","*"],["8","1"],["8","8"],["8","/"],["8","9"],["8","-"],["8","5"],["8","*"],["/","1"],["/","8"],["/","/"],["/","9"],["/","-"],["/","5"],["/","*"],["9","1"],["9","8"],["9","/"],["9","9"],["9","-"],["9","5"],["9","*"],["-","1"],["-","8"],["-","/"],["-","9"],["-","-"],["-","5"],["-","*"],["5","1"],["5","8"],["5","/"],["5","9"],["5","-"],["5","5"],["5","*"],["*","1"],["*","8"],["*","/"],["*","9"],["*","-"],["*","5"],["*","*"]]
    ʒ  }       # Filter it by:
     Ë_        #  Where both characters are unique
               #   i.e. → [["1","8"],["1","/"],["1","9"],["1","-"],["1","5"],["1","*"],["8","1"],["8","/"],["8","9"],["8","-"],["8","5"],["8","*"],["/","1"],["/","8"],["/","9"],["/","-"],["/","5"],["/","*"],["9","1"],["9","8"],["9","/"],["9","-"],["9","5"],["9","*"],["-","1"],["-","8"],["-","/"],["-","9"],["-","5"],["-","*"],["5","1"],["5","8"],["5","/"],["5","9"],["5","-"],["5","*"],["*","1"],["*","8"],["*","/"],["*","9"],["*","-"],["*","5"]]
    ʒ          # Then filter the pairs again by:
     ¹         #  Push the first input-list with equations
      s        #  Swap to take the pair we're filtering
       Â       #  Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate and Reverse)
        ‡      #  Transliterate; replacing the characters at the same indices in the input-list
               #   i.e. ["18/18","98-8","55*88","-5--15"] and ["8","5"]
               #    → ["15/15","95-5","88*55","-8--18"]
               #   i.e. ["9119","5-3","8*-9","13116/3"] and ["1","-"]
               #    → ["9--9","513","8*19","-3--6/3"]
      „--'+:  '#  Then replace all "--" with a "+"
               #   → ["15/15","95-5","88*55","-8+18"]
               #   → ["9+9","513","8*19","-3+6/3"]
      .E       #  And evaluate the strings with Python eval
               #   → [1.0,90,4840,10]
               #   → [18,513,152,-1.0]
        Q      #  And then check if this evaluated list is equal to the (implicit) second input
               #   i.e. [1.0,90,4840,10] and [1,90,4840,10] → 1 (truthy)
               #   i.e. [18,513,152,-1.0] and [18,513,152,-1] → 1 (truthy)
               # (and output the result implicitly)
               #   i.e. [["8","5"],["5","8"]
               #   i.e. [["1","-"],["-","1"]
```